# Compare difference in two json files and out put the difference

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to compare difference between two json files and output the list of r_id values which are present in file a but not in file b.

Json files which i am trying to compare

File a =

```
   {“r_id”:”123”,"RefNumber”:”2341234131","amount":"22.99”},
   {“r_id”:”345”,"RefNumber”:”2341234131","amount":"22.99”},
   {“r_id”:”678”,"RefNumber”:”2341234131","amount":"22.99”}
```

File b =

```
     {“name” : “James”, "id" : “123”, “class” : “1A”},
     {“name” : “Sam”,"id" : “345”, “class” : “1A”},
     {“name” : “Jen”,"id" : “005”, “class” : “1A”}
```

Comparison should be based on id's in both files. Expecting following output in difference file

```
{“r_id”:”678”,"RefNumber”:”2341234131","amount":"22.99”}
```

Comment: Rich text quotes aren't valid Python and are annoying to work with. I recommend using ascii quotes to make this question easier to answer. Also, `File a`--what is this? A list of dicts (array of objects in JSON)? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: File a is json file. Yes its array of objects in JSON.

Comment: OK, if it's an array I'd recommend adding `[]`s to it to make it valid.

Comment: Apologise json data is included in [ ]. 
It was formatted when i post the session.

Comment: Tried following code and i am getting 

NameError: name 'file_a' is not defined

import json

json1 = json.load(open("./cam_local_file.json", "r"))
json2 = json.load(open("./cbs_local_file.json", "r"))


items_a = {value['transaction_id']: value for value in file_a},
items_b = {value['requestId']: value for value in file_b},
diff_keys = set(items_a) ^ set(items_b),
diff_items = {items_a[key] if items_a.has_key(key) else items_b[key] for key in diff_keys},

json.dumps(diff_items, open('file_diff.json'))

Comment: This is unreadable. If you're asking for help, make it easy for people to help you. Edit the code into your post, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212107/discussion-between-user29496-and-ggorlen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if ids are not in order and jsons don't have equal items.

```
import json

with open("json_a.json","r") as first, open("json_b.json","r") as second :
  b =  json.load(first,object_pairs_hook=lambda x: x[0])
  c =  json.load(second,object_pairs_hook=lambda x: x[1])

b = [ _[1] for _ in b]
c = [ _[1] for _ in c]

with open("json_a.json","r") as first:
  for each_line in json.load(first):
    for uniq_id in list(set(b).difference(c)):
      if each_line['r_id']== uniq_id :
        print(each_line)
```

Another approach:

```
import json

with open("json_a.json","r") as first, open("json_b.json","r") as second :
  b =  json.load(first)
  c =  json.load(second)

b_ids=[x['r_id'] for x in b]

c_ids=[x['id'] for x in c]

for each_item in b:
  for uniq_id in list(set(b_ids).difference(c_ids)):
    if each_item['r_id'] == uniq_id:
      print(each_item)
```

Write to file:

```
# Serializing json
json_object = json.dumps(each_item)

# Writing to sample.json 
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile: 
    outfile.write(json_object)
```

More details about file writing options can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp).

Comment: Sorry for naivety. How can i output the result to another file? Difference is written to the terminal. Would like to save it to a file in current working directory.

Comment: Np. Added at the end of answer. Used `w` but perhaps `a` should be used. Included a link for more details. Instead of `print(..)` use the last block (inside of loop) with 'a' instead of 'w'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code :

```
import json

a = ['{"r_id":"123","RefNumber":"2341234131","amount":"22.99"}',
     '{"r_id":"345","RefNumber":"2341234131","amount":"22.99"}',
     '{"r_id":"678","RefNumber":"2341234131","amount":"22.99"}'
   ]


b = [ '{"name" : "James", "id" : "123", "class" : "1A"}',
      '{"name" : "Sam", "id" : "345", "class" : "1A"}',
      '{"name" : "Jen", "id" : "005", "class" : "1A"}'
     ]


for i in range(len(a)):
    y = json.loads(a[i])
    z = json.loads(b[i])
    if y["r_id"] != z["id"]:
        print(a[i])
```

Output :

```
{"r_id":"678","RefNumber":"2341234131","amount":"22.99"}
```

Before working with json files the file should be like below format :

```
[{"r_id":"123","RefNumber":"2341234131","amount":"22.99"},
 {"r_id":"345","RefNumber":"2341234131","amount":"22.99"},
 {"r_id":"678","RefNumber":"2341234131","amount":"22.99"}
]
```

Try with this code(with files):

```
import json

with open('file1.json','r') as a:
    data1 = a.read()
obj1 = json.loads(data1)

with open('file2.json','r') as a:
    data2 = a.read()
obj2 = json.loads(data2)

count = 0
for i in obj1:
    a = obj2[count]
    if i["r_id"] != a["id"]:
        print(i)
    count = count + 1
```

Output is same as above.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this . I am getting following error.                                                   
 raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: from a file. 
these files are stored in current working directory in Pycharm

Comment: also what if the jsons are not ordered?

Comment: I added code which takes the json files as input and provides the output.